# Is Spring Data Jpa findOne method return managed entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller that serves *POST* request (file uploading) but actually provides an update. The logic is pretty straightforward :
 - find object by id
 - if we don't have such object return BAD_REQUEST 
 - otherwise update found object and return updated as *ResponseEntity*

```
@PostMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> post(@PathVariable("id") long id, 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    //this is not @Transactional method
    Optional<Job> jobOptional = jobService.getJobById(id);
    return jobOptional
            .map(
                job -> 
                    getSuccessfulResponse(
                        //this is @Transactional
                        jobService.update(job, file))) //1 
            .orElse(
                getBadRequestResponse(
                    getJobNotFoundByIdMessage(id)));

}
[...]
@Service
public class JobService {

    @Transactional
    public Job update(Job job, MultipartFile file) {...}

}
```

At *1* we updating retrieved (finally by `CrudRepository#findOne`) entity and give updated and saved into DB value back.

My question is : can we mutate method parameter and give back this mutated result or should we make clone parameter inside method, mutate it then give result back?

In terms of jpa/hibernate : does `CrudRepository#findOne` gives us a `managed/attached` entity? I personally suppose - no, cause method that invokes it doesn't marked `@Transactional` and we can clone it, invoke `CrudRepository#save` to provide an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring data-jpa repositories methods are wrapped with @Transactional.
In order to have your entity passed back as managed you need to wrap your public method calling the repository method with @Transactional.

Thus the transaction will be in a higher level.

For example

```
@Transactional
public void makeChanges(Long id) {

   User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
   user.setName("Someone");
}
```

At the end of the transaction your changes shall be saved since user is a managed entity.

You can change your service to pass back Optional whether the entity exists or not. For example

```
@Transactional public Optional<Job> update(Job job, MultipartFile file) {...}
```

If entity does not exist then optional is empty. If entity exists then optional contains the entity after the update.

Comment: it is already wrapped as i mentioned in question. and i am not sure. that it is good idea to retrieve the same entity twice. thank you for `Spring data-jpa repositories methods are wrapped with @Transactional`. i didn't know that. Actually it is `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

Comment: You can change your service to pass back Optional whether the entity exists or not. For example

@Transactional public Optional<Job> update(Job job, MultipartFile file) {...}
If entity does not exist then optional is empty. If entity exists then optional contains the entity after the update.